# I'm trying to create a new user in IAM programatically

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm  new to programming. I need to figure out how I can create AWS users, roles and policies programmatically using code.

That task I'm after :

1. Create a User, Role and Policy
2. Assign Policy to the Role
3. Assign Role to the User
4. Set condition on the Role, that only Users with MFA can assume that Role
5. Config's should live in S3 bucket
6. configure a LAMBDA to check the user's role membership and output the result to S3 bucket.

Just trying to figure out where do I start from ? I have a very limited programming experience (can do a bit of PHP).

I have a AWS account, created a user and gave him 'AdministratorAccess' also have user keys for CLI access.

Should I be suing  1)AWS CLI 2) Powershell 3) AWS SDK's 4) AWS API?

Appreciate any help/direction to achieve the above.

Thanks
S

Comment: If you have to create these using programming, then you need to use the SDK, but if you are new to programming this is pretty advanced.  Usually users, roles and policies are created with the CLI or via the web console.

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically create IAM Roles you can use [AWS PHP SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/). Refer the [IAM Create User section](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-iam-2010-05-08.html#createuser) in SDK API reference for more details.

Comment: Thank much for the response. I've been able  to complete this using python boto3 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using specific language AWS SDKs such as suggested by @Ashan, you can do so by using AWS REST API with the following example request:

```
https://iam.amazonaws.com/?Action=CreateUser
&Path=/division_abc/subdivision_xyz/
&UserName=Bob
&Version=2010-05-08
&AUTHPARAMS
```

Source - [CreateUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_CreateUser.html)